# ExecuteNonQuery() Returns unexpected number of rows affected C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Here's my code

```
      // SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO devis (idProposition, identreprise, tauxHoraire, fraisGenerauxMO, fraisGenerauxPiece, beneficeEtAleas, idStatut, prixUnitaireVenteMO ) VALUES(@idproposition,  @identreprise, @tauxHoraire, @fraisGenerauxMO, @fraisGenerauxPiece, @beneficeEtAleas, 1, @prixUnitaireVenteMO) ", Tools.GetConnection());
     SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO devis (idProposition, identreprise, tauxHoraire, fraisGenerauxMO, fraisGenerauxPiece, beneficeEtAleas, idStatut, prixUnitaireVenteMO, alerteEntrepriseEnvoyee,fraisDeplacement ) VALUES(1051,  85, 20, 2, 2, 2.2, 1, 88,0,-1) ", Tools.GetConnection());

    //query.Parameters.AddWithValue("idproposition", this.ID);
    //query.Parameters.AddWithValue("identreprise", competitor.ID);
    //query.Parameters.AddWithValue("tauxHoraire", competitor.CoefTauxHoraire);
    //query.Parameters.AddWithValue("fraisGenerauxMO", competitor.CoefFraisGenerauxMO);
    //query.Parameters.AddWithValue("fraisGenerauxPiece", competitor.CoefFraisGenerauxPiece);
    //query.Parameters.AddWithValue("beneficeEtAleas", competitor.CoefBeneficeEtAleas);
    //query.Parameters.AddWithValue("prixUnitaireVenteMO", Math.Round(competitor.CoefTauxHoraire * competitor.CoefFraisGenerauxMO * competitor.CoefBeneficeEtAleas, 2));
 bool insertOK = (query.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1);
 if (insertOK)
 {
    // DO SOMETHING
 }
```

`insertOk` is false but in the database the row is inserted with all the information that I specified

I rebuilt the query manually to see if the problem came from the query.Parameters, it inserts without error again into the database but insertOk is still false! I even added two other fields which aren't supposed to be null but the activity is the same in both cases

any ideas?

Comment: Well what value does `ExecuteNonQuery()` return? 0? 2? 100?

Comment: No of rows effected in Database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command.

When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

Comment: This is a literal copy paste from MSDN.

Comment: ah I have a trigger on the table that inserts a row into another table that's why

thanks for the help

Comment: It is a literal copy from msdn which explains the possible causes of the mismatch.

Comment: @MikeBryant You accepted the answer copied from _MSDN_? Really? :)

Comment: It was the answer that led me to the solution
I guess I'm just having one of those days when the obvious is oblivious to me

Answer (score 8):

`ExecuteNonQuery` it claims to return `The number of rows affected.`. This is incorrect, as there is no way for the client to know the number of rows affected. The documentation incorrectly assumes that the engine will report the number of rows affected, but that is subject to the session [`SET NOCOUNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx) state. Do not write code that assumes the NOCOUNT is always on. If you need to know the number of rows affected use the [`OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx). Relying on the `@@ROWCOUNT` or the `SET NOCOUNT` state is subject to many many corner cases where the value is incorrect from one point of view or another.

Answer (score 1):

[`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) method returns [`System.Int32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx)

> Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns
>   the number of rows affected.

```
Return Value
Type: System.Int32
The number of rows affected.
```

Since your `query.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns `2`, it is too obvious `2 == 1` returns `false`.

Your query will be;

```
bool insertOK = (2 == 1);
```

[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/3W5Uzy).

Comment: yeah, i've changed it now to 

bool insertOK = (query.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0);

Comment: @mike Bryant if it returns size System.INT32 it always returns 2 even its faild.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SqlDataAdapter`  such that :

```
SqlDataAdapter Adabter = new SqlDataAdapter();
 Adabter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO devis values(@idProposition, @identreprise), Tools.GetConnection());

 Adabter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@idproposition",SqlDbType.Int).Value = yorID;
 Adabter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@identreprise", SqlDbType.Int).Value = yorID;

 Tools.OpenConnection();
 int result = Adabter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 Tools.CloseConnection();

if( result  > 0 )
{
                MessageBox.Show("Information Added");
}else
{
                  MessageBox.Show("Error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here with an UPDATE query. In my case I had to add "set nocount off" to the SQL. Example code:

```
string sql =
$@"set nocount off;update PRODUCT_PLAN 
                                set WORKING_STATUS = 'P', 
                                user_id = @USER_ID
                   where workorder_base_id = @BASE_ID 
  ";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.CommandType =CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER_ID", opl.USER_ID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BASE_ID", opl.WORKORDER_BASE_ID);

cmd.CommandText = sql;

// Nr of rows updated in retval
int retval = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```