# ExecuteNonQuery returns -1 (incorrectly)

Tags: vb.net, sqlcommand, executenonquery

I inherited an old VB Website the uses ExecuteNonQuery to modify passwords.  In our production environment, sql server 2008 R2, I've had recent reports of broken functionality.  It turns out the ExecuteNonQuery is returning -1 when in fact the data is getting updated (a single row).  When I copied the data to our dev environment, the rows affected is 1 as expected.  We have a different service packs applied (4XXX vs 6XXX) and I wonder if this is the issue?  I modified the code to use ExecuteScalar to inspect the RowCount, and this is working. But I shouldn't have to do so.  Any insight?   I have now idea how long this has been broken.

Here's the original code, that returns -1 erroneously.  It is not calling a stored procedure and there are no triggers involved.

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE UserMaster " & _
           " SET Password = @Password, LastPasswordChangedDate = @LastPasswordChangedDate " & _
           " WHERE Username = @UserName AND ApplicationName = @ApplicationName ", conn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = CreateHash(newPwd)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastPasswordChangedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = username.TrimEnd
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApplicationName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = Left(pApplicationName, 1)

Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0
Try
    conn.Open()
    rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This code returns a 1 as expected:

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE UserMaster " & _
           " SET Password = @Password, LastPasswordChangedDate = @LastPasswordChangedDate " & _
           " WHERE Username = @UserName AND ApplicationName = @ApplicationName ; select @@rowcount", conn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = CreateHash(newPwd)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastPasswordChangedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = username.TrimEnd
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApplicationName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = Left(pApplicationName, 1)

Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0
Try
    conn.Open()
    rowsAffected = CType(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
```

Comment: `SET NOCOUNT OFF;` add that before your update. When on it prevents extra result sets from interfering with select statements... I don't recommend this approach and you should leave it on... Your doing a simple update so it shouldn't be a problem.. Another option is declare an ouput param and then set it after the update. When executed you would have the rowcount... Or just select the rowcount like you are.

Comment: Do you have trigger on that table? If yes, this could be help (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15702169/1050927)

Comment: @Alex OP said there's no triggers...last sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Setting NOCOUNT OFF also corrected the issue.  What's odd is that when I checked the variable in the system, it said it was already off.  Time to move on!

Answer (score 0):

`ExceuteNonQuery` returns -1 for all stored procedures as per the [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx#See%20Also) documentation.

It will return the updated records' number only in case of a statement.